# Why openssl_sign is not signing my pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, php-openssl

I tried to sign pdf with my digital signature on php with openssl_sign, but this not work.

```php
$private = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents("./certificate.pem"));

$public = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents("./certificate.pem"));

$data = file_get_contents("./mypdf.pdf");

openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

file_put_contents('signature.dat', $signature);

$r = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public, "sha256WithRSAEncryption");
```

when I open pdf with adobe reader is not show me that pdf is not signed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Because the PDF format doesn't work that way. Signatures are included in the PDF file, not stored as a separate file.

Use an existing library like TCPDF to sign PDFs.